# Unbale to set Custom Login page in Experience Builder

Tags: customer-community, experience-builder-page

I am trying to select custom login page in by experience builder, however it is not changing the login page, it is howing default login page.

I also set the custom login page as default, but still it is same.

[image]

[image]

**OUTPUT what I am seeing:**

[image]

**Administration Setup:**

[image]

Comment: My guess is that audience cannot be used here (the user cannot be mapped to an audience until after login) and that you need instead to either update the standard page or add a new one and select it in the Login Page selection set in the experience' Administration workspace.

Comment: Yes, I already have login page selected in Admin Setup. I dont see any other custom login page to select.